# ¿Por qué redirigir la salida de un archivo a ese mismo archivo provoca que se borre su contenido?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

No entiendo por qué `cat archivo.txt > archivo.txt` (siendo el mismo archivo), no funciona y que cree un archivo vacío.

¿Conoce alguien alguna alternativa para arreglar esto? Lo necesito para un pequeño script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre básicamente es que `bash` (lee de derecha a izquierda) procesando en primer lugar el redireccionamiento `>` que trunca el archivo de entrada `archivo.txt` y luego recién ejecuta el comando `cat`, pero a ese momento, el archivo ya está vacío.

Soluciones posibles:

- Usar un archivo intermedio: `cat archivo.txt > archivo.txt.$$ && mv archivo.txt.$$ archivo.txt`
- Evitar el archivo intermediario a expensas de una posible pérdida parcial o total de datos en caso de que se produzca un error o interrupción. En este ejemplo, el contenido de `archivo.txt` se pasa como entrada a un subshell (dentro de los paréntesis) antes de borrarlo. El inodo anterior se mantiene vivo ya que el subshell lo mantiene abierto mientras se leen los datos. El archivo escrito por la utilidad interna (`cat`) con el mismo nombre (`archivo.txt`) apunta a un inodo diferente porque la entrada antigua del directorio ha sido eliminada, técnicamente, hay dos "archivos" diferentes con el mismo nombre durante el proceso. Cuando el subshell termina, el viejo inodo se libera y sus datos se pierden. Tenga cuidado por asegurarse de tener espacio suficiente para almacenar temporalmente tanto el archivo antiguo como el nuevo al mismo tiempo, de lo contrario perderá datos.

  ```
  (rm archivo.txt; cat > archivo.txt) < archivo.txt
  ```

Traducida de: [Why does redirecting the output of a file to itself produce a blank file?](https://superuser.com/a/597257)

En algunos foros recomiendan también usar [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) una herramienta no estándar, pero eventualmente de fácil instalación. Según su descripción:

```
DESCRIPTION
  sponge  reads  standard  input  and writes it out to the specified file. Unlike
  a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before opening the output file.
  This allows for constructing pipelines that read from and write to the same 
  file.
```

Podrías hacer entonces:

```
cat archivo.txt | sponge archivo.txt
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación Patricio, yo usé archivos intermedios y funcionaba correctamente pero el código quedaba bastante feo, usaré la herramienta sponge.

Comment: Bien indicado. La clave aquí es que la shell lee de derecha a izquierda, por lo que primero hace `> fichero` (y elimina su contenido) y luego el resto.

Comment: @fedorqui, es cierto, agrego tu comentario a la respuesta, gracias..